# Given a graph of velocity versus time for a particle, how to plot the graph of speed versus time?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

Given a graph of velocity versus time for a particle, how can I plot the graph of speed versus time for that particle? What I think is I just have to reflect the part below x-axis through x-axis. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri Thanks.